# Canonical map in the direct image of $\mathscr{D}_X$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, d-modules

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a proper holomorphic map between holomorphic manifolds. We work with $\mathscr{D}$-modules. Consider the transfer bi-modules $\mathscr{D}_{Y\leftarrow X}.$ Can one find a canonical arrow $$\Omega_Y \to \Omega_Y \otimes_{\mathscr{D}_Y} f_+(\mathscr{D}_X) := \Omega_Y \overset{L}\otimes_{\mathscr{D}_Y}Rf_*(\mathscr{D}_{Y \leftarrow X}) \,\,\, ?$$ In some sense, I would like to use the canonical section $1_{Y \leftarrow X}$ but the derived functor makes things more complicated. If it is impossible in the general case, one can assume that the manifolds are $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. Thanks for any help.